# Is it possible to use Azure CLI to configure deployment to an app service from a Dropbox location?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

So I'm following this guide in order tosuse Azure 2.0 CLI to create an app service to deploy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started

I have set up the resource group, the app service plan and the app but instead of setting up the deployment with a Git repository like this

```
 az appservice web source-control config-local-git --name <app_name> --resource-group my-first-app-group
```

I would like to put all my files into a folder in DropBox.

This step can be done by using the Azure web site but I would like to know if it is possible to using the Azure 2.0 CLI? If so, what is the command?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to put all my files into a folder in DropBox.
>   This step can be done by using the Azure web site but I would like to
>   know if it is possible to using the Azure 2.0 CLI?

We can use CLI 2.0 command like this:

```
C:\Users>az appservice web source-control config --repo-url https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ar7n31ozqgchnb2/AABxdZN4v4pklk3USCnFBWdVa?dl=0 --repository-type mercurial --name jasonapp2 --resource ubuntu
```

Here is my result:

```
C:\Users>az appservice web source-control config --repo-url https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ar7n31ozqgchnb2/AABxdZN4v4pklk3USCnFBWdVa?dl=0 --repository-type mercurial --name jasonapp2 --resource ubuntu
{
  "branch": null,
  "deploymentRollbackEnabled": false,
  "id": "/subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0361e29a7b15/resourceGroups/ubuntu/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/jasonapp2/sourcecontrols/web",
  "isManualIntegration": false,
  "isMercurial": false,
  "kind": null,
  "location": "Central US",
  "name": "jasonapp2",
  "repoUrl": "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ar7n31ozqgchnb2/AABxdZN4v4pklk3USCnFBWdVa?dl=0",
  "resourceGroup": "ubuntu",
  "tags": {
    "hidden-related:/subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0361e29a7b15/resourcegroups/AppResource/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/palian160919": "empty"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance